# Do you know any OS independend centralized backup solution?

Tags: linux, windows, backup, home-server

I'm currently looking for a new backup solution for my home network. That's my IT infrastructure: - HomeServer with OpenMediaVault on Debian - 1 Arch Linux Client - 3 Windows Clients (7/8/10) - 1 RasPi on Debian

It should manage a normal file backup and bare-metal backup (differential with some full backups)

I was searching the internet multiple hours now for an backup solution which is not that difficult to configure but delivers a server component to handle the backups with an web-interface and a client (deamon/service) for Windows and Linux system which will push the data to the server.

My old system was an WHS2003 which offers this functionality to Windows Clients. Is there anything similar which offers this to Windows and Linux, based on a Linux Server?

Comment: What is wrong with using a NAS then on each system implementing an OS specific backup plan.

Comment: That's how it is set up at the moment, but I'm not really happy with it.

Comment: Define "not happy with it"

Comment: You want a cross-platform solution.  You want a Linux based solution.  There are numerous solutions, they are just NAS solutions, there isn't a good way to handle bare-metal backup across multiple platforms using a single software package.

Comment: @Moab A central management is much more comfortable. I would be able to manage schedules, type of backup, affected files at one point. With the current solution I have to login to the every client, do the changes and save it. Since I'm logged out, I have no overview of the backup settings.

Comment: @Ramhound the bare-metal solution is most important for the windows machines (especially my main-nb which I use for work, and the nb of my wife which are both running Windows (7/8.1). Currently I'm using the backup-SW from AOMEI Backuper which is saving the backups to the NAS. But no central management.

Comment: There is plenty of software that handles cross-platform backups with central management but a lot of the better ones cost money - you don't mention if you are after a free solution or are willing to pay for software.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq I'm primary looking for a free solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found in urbackup the backup tool which fits my needs and was realy easy to install and configure.

http://www.urbackup.org/

The first file-backup was finished in about 10minutes after the download.

Comment: I see it has an active community forum and someone wrote instructions on how to restore by [PXE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) at [Restoring Images from PXE](https://urbackup.atlassian.net/wiki/display/US/Restoring+Images+from+PXE), so I think it may be a good choice for me at a site where I currently use very outdated backup software.

Comment: Just a short note, as I stumbled over this: The UrBackup Server does not support IPv6 (https://forums.urbackup.org/t/does-urbackup-offer-ipv6-support/3608)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [Bacula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacula) ([screenshots](http://blog.bacula.org/documentation/screenshots/), [manual](http://blog.bacula.org/documentation/documentation/)) might work for you.

> Bacula is an open source, enterprise level computer backup system for
>   heterogeneous networks. It is designed to automate backup tasks that
>   had often required intervention from a systems administrator or
>   computer operator.
>
> Bacula supports Linux, UNIX, Windows, and Mac OS X backup clients, and
>   a range of professional backup devices including tape libraries.
>   Administrators and operators can configure the system via a command
>   line console, GUI or web interface; its back-end is a catalog of
>   information stored by MySQL, PostgreSQL, or SQLite.

It supports bare metal recovery - see [Disaster Recovery Using Bacula](http://www.bacula.org/5.0.x-manuals/en/main/main/Disaster_Recovery_Using_Bac.html).

Comment: I also had a look on it, but wasn't able to install it on my test-machine for a short test. But I think I should give it another try. Are you using it by yourself?

Comment: Bacua has a fork called bareos. Bareos is in debian jessie, in wheezy there is bacula, but the bacula wheezy pacages have some problems.

Comment: @Daniel. I'm not using Bacula myself currently; installing it is on my "to do" list for my home network. I suggested it since it is used by the systems group where I work to backup mission critical systems. We're using CentOS for new Linux systems, but the prior team lead for the systems group liked Debian and that distribution was used, so I thought it should work for your Debian server and I've seen some installation guides for Debian online, e.g., [Bacula installation in Debian](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/bacula2.htm).

Comment: @moonpoint after many hours of testing, Bacula is too much overpowered and not that easy to handle ... I think I got a better solution for my needs in UrBackup but thanks for your proposal